# (Lubuntu) Can't open onboard keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

Ok so i'm in need of a virtual keyboard. I installed onboard, but when I try and open in it I get this message...

```
 ** (onboard:1573): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
12:00:01.098 WARNING Config: mousetweaks GSettings schema not found, mousetweaks integration disabled.

** (onboard:1573): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

** (onboard:1573): ERROR **: AT-SPI: COuldn't connect to accessibility bus. Is at-spi-bus-launcher running?
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

(PS) I've been copying and pasting letters from here lol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet

Comment: I would like to know which version of lubuntu. in the main lubuntu menu at the left hand corener there is a character map which will allow you to copy and paste. Also this might be a bug and do you have the mousetweaks package installed. I installed on 15.04 without mousetweaks and got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have just met with the same problem and I have a solution.

My onboard keyboard was working until I went to play with the settings. In particular the settings regarding word suggestions

Launch "dconf Editor"
Applications -> System Tools -> dconf Editor

go to 
org -> onboard -> typing assistance -> word-suggestions

untick the "enabled" checkbox and close dconf Editor.

onboard should start now.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!  So, does it mean I cannot use the `word-suggestions` option?

Answer (score 0):

Open **Onboard Settings** which can be found in **Preferences**. In the *General* tab, make sure *Auto-show when editing text* is unticked.

Also if *Start Onboard hidden* is ticked, you can find the onboard icon on the panel to open the virtual keyboard.